# How do I get output file in xml format after I blast sequences in R?

Tags: r

```
for (i in 1:2) { 
    query_fn <- paste0("data/query_sequences/query",as.character(i),".txt") 
    output_fn <- paste0("data/output/output",as.character(i),".txt")
    system(paste("tblastn -query", query_fn, "-db data/genomes/bac_gen_db -out", output_fn)) 
}
```

This is my code. But I want output in xml format. It does not give xml formatted output if I change .txt to .xml

Answer (score 0):

It's really not a program question. You should specify the parameter of tblastn to get the desired output format. Here "-outfmt 5". See http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK279675/

```
for (i in 1:2) { 
    query_fn <- paste0("data/query_sequences/query",as.character(i),".txt") 
    output_fn <- paste0("data/output/output",as.character(i),".xml")
    system(paste("tblastn -query", query_fn, "-db data/genomes/bac_gen_db -outfmt  -out", output_fn)) 
}
```